# Angular, typescript, google charts - Type (Date|number)[][] is not assignable to type Array<Array<string|number>>

Tags: angular, typescript, google-visualization

I use angular 8 with google charts module.

I tried to create a  [Google Calendar Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar) to add it to some other already working google charts.

However, in my component.html when I pass on the data,
I get an error (warning by the IDE) that `Type (Date|number)[][] is not assignable to type Array<Array<string|number>>`. I am at a loss because to me it seems that I pass on the 2D array of Dates and Values as required.

Although my front-end does compile, when I go to the page with the google calendar, the page crashes/gets stuck.

My *something.component.html*:

```
<google-chart
            [type]="Calendar"
            [data]="calendarChartData"  <----------------------- HERE IS THE ERROR
            [columnNames]="calendarChartColumnNames"
            [options]="calendarChartOptions">
</google-chart>
```

My *something.component.ts*:

```
calendarChartOptions = {
    title: 'Some title',
    height: 350,
    calendar: {
      dayOfWeekLabel: {
        fontName: 'Times-Roman',
        fontSize: 12,
        color: '#1a8763',
        bold: true,
        italic: true,
      },
      dayOfWeekRightSpace: 10,
      cellSize: 10,
    }
  };
  calendarChartColumnNames = ['Date', 'someNumber'];
  calendarChartData = [
    [new Date(2019, 3, 13), 333],
    [new Date(2019, 9, 16), 372],
    [new Date(2019, 9, 17), 5333],
    [new Date(2019, 9, 18), 3702],
    [new Date(2019, 9, 19), 3103],
    [new Date(2019, 9, 20), 2244],
    [new Date(2019, 9, 21), 9531],
    [new Date(2019, 9, 22), 5503]
  ];
```

My *something.module.ts*:

```
...
import { GoogleChartsModule } from 'angular-google-charts';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used Google Charts before...

From the error it sounds like all you need to do is convert your dates to strings..

```
...
calendarChartData = [
    [new Date(2019, 3, 13).toISOString(), 333],
    [new Date(2019, 3, 13).toDateString(), 333], // not sure exactly which format the module requires.
    ...
  ];
```

Comment: Both ```.toISOString()``` and ```.toDateString()``` remove the warning but then I get ```Invalid data table format: column #0 must be of type 'date|datetime' .``` This is a whole new level of confusing for me as at first it wants a string, then it wants a date when the date is converted to a string.

Comment: @curiousMinded is that an error or a warning? Looking back at your question, have you considered that maybe your IDE is just giving the wrong warning? or maybe you have the wrong `.d.ts` file for the module (somehow)?

Comment: I don't think the warning is wrong - the code does compile but the produced page crashes the browser tab (so it's a warning on paper but is actually a noticable error). If I listen to IDE and do something to remove the error or comment that code away, no crashes occur. I think the module settings are fine because everything else including other google charts on the same page works fine.